# The site determines that I use selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I ask for help, I came across this for the first time.

This site https://kad.arbitr.ru/, if you open it with selenium, somehow defines that and bottom - doesn't work. And further attempts to do something - fail. I did not see this either on Instagram, or on Facebook, or on Twitter. Maybe someone saw such sites?

I tried start selenium with cookies, headless, with PhantomJS - Nothing works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://kad.arbitr.ru/")

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class, "b-promo_notification-popup")]')))
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("First")

try:
    exit_promo = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/a[@class="b-promo_notification-popup-close js-promo_notification-popup-close"]')))
    exit_promo.click()
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Second")

search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("g-ph")[0]
search.send_keys("Linkkeys Entrerprazes LTD")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The fact is, I don’t understand what it can be

UPD 1.
On site we can see that button. Button work when I open site in Google Chrome or another browser and press. But when I try it with selenium - nothing.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _somehow defines that and bottom - doesn't work_? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB Look please UPD 1.